ROM update SO-2k to g8441 Sony xperia XZ1 compact
I have intended to update my sony xperia xz1 compact from stock ROM android 9 to customized ROM, but had an error messages, because of there is japan ROM installed SO-2k, and when i try to flash it by the Newflasher program, i get
- Extracting from partition-image-LUN0_X-FLASH-ALL-C93B.sin
- Extracting signature partitionimage_0.cms
- Uploading signature d:\sony\downloads\g8441_uk11228.228-R2C\partition\partitionimage_0.cms
  signature:0000053c
  Error, didn't got signature OKAY reply!           Got reply: FAILFailed to verify cms

similar message, just not as detal get from Flashtool program
06/000/2024 18:00:28 - INFO  - Sending Get-root-key-hash
06/000/2024 18:00:28 - INFO  -    Get-root-key-hash status : OKAY
06/000/2024 18:00:28 - INFO  - Connected device : SO-02K / SW release 1307-7513_47.2.B.5.38 / Customization 1311-8845_R11C
06/000/2024 18:00:28 - INFO  - Last flash date : 2024-10-05 22:34:26
06/000/2024 18:00:28 - INFO  - Phone ready for flashmode operations.
06/000/2024 18:00:28 - ***ERROR - The bundle does not match the connected device***

I had tryed the UK and hk distributives, not successful, does there any way to flash any ROM, except the native SO-2K ?
And i can't to unlock the SO-2K ROM to TWRP install.
My target OS is LineageOS 18 or 21, but it will be fine, if i can flash any stock OS, G8441, i hope it will help me to reach the target OS install.
Does there any way? May be the Fastboot/ADB is possible to use?   or something else?

Have you unlocked your bootloader first? Without unlocked bootloader the phone only accepts firmware signed by the manufacturer for your device model. That may be causing this signature error.

the problem is, that i can made OEM unlock in Developer settings. I can't unlock with the developer code, it's not accepted by these Docomo  ROM's
So, i need to flash global ROM or unlocked SO-2k japan ROM, but i can flash the native ROM only, and i need way, how to do it.

If the phone doesn't accept the global ROM and you can not unlock bootloader then you are stuck. The only theoretical path left would be an exploit that would be an exploit that somehow allows you to enable OEM unlock/bootloader unlocking, but that you have to search yourself as I don't know any. For an older Qualcom chipset there was found a workaround: https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/breaking-the-android-bootloader-on-the-qualcomm-snapdragon-660/
